Showing that two continuous distributions are the same
Let $\mathcal{U}[a,b]$ be the uniform distribution over a (continuous) interval $a$ to $b$ and let $t$ be, such that $a \leq t \leq b$.
Say I consider two experiments:

Sample a value $x$ from $\mathcal{U}[a,b]$ and output it.

Sample a value $x$ from $\mathcal{U}[a,b]$. If $x > t$, then return $x$. If $x \leq t$, then sample a uniformly random value from $\mathcal{U}[a,t]$ and output it.


Intuitively these two experiments should produce the same distribution of outputs.
In the second experiment, learning that the first value was in $\leq t$, I should only know that it is uniform in $[a, t]$, thus if I just sampled another fresh uniformly random value from that interval, then I should not have changed the original distribution.
Question:
How do I show that these two distributions are identical formally step by step?
In the case of a discrete distribution, I could just analyze the probability of any individual outcome, but in the case of a continuous distribution any single output has probability 0, if I understand correctly. Thus I need a different approach, but it is not clear to me what that should be.

They should not output the same distribution of solutions. The first distribution will be U([a,b]) while the second will be the distribution U([a,t]).

Not following.  In distribution $#2$, what do you do if $x>t$?  Did you mean to say that, in that case, you keep the sample value $x$?

Sorry I was not clear. I edited the question. If the value is > t, then you just return that value

As to strategy, it's much the same as in the discrete case. pick an interval $[c,d]$ in the given interval, so $a≤c≤d≤b$ and argue that the probability that your sample in in $[c,d]$ is as expected ($\frac {d-c}{b-a}$).  Helps to first argue that it's enough to handle the two cases $c≥t$ and $d≤t$

Without loss of generality, assume $a = 0$, $b = 1$.  Let $X \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$ and let $t \in (0,1)$ be a fixed parameter.
The conditional distribution of $X \mid X \le t$ is uniform on $[0,t]$, so resampling from the same distribution will not change the unconditional (marginal) distribution.
Specifically, let $Y \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,t)$.  Then your sampling procedure may be written as the random variable
$$Z = \begin{cases}Y, & X \le t \\ X, & X > t. \end{cases}$$
We want to show $\Pr[Z \le x] = \Pr[X \le x] = x$.  To this end, consider the case $x \le t$.  Then
$$\Pr[Z \le x] = \Pr[(Y \le x) \cap (X \le t)] = \Pr[Y \le x]\Pr[X \le t] = \frac{x}{t} \cdot \frac{t}{1} = x.$$
Next, consider the case $x > t$.  Then
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[Z \le x] 
&= \Pr[Z \le x \mid X \le t]\Pr[X \le t] + \Pr[Z \le x \mid X > t]\Pr[X > t] \\
&= \Pr[Y \le x]\Pr[X \le t] + \Pr[X \le x \mid X > t]\Pr[X > t] \\
&= \Pr[Y \le t]\Pr[X \le t] + \Pr[t < X \le x] \\
&= 1 \cdot t + \frac{x-t}{1} \\
&= x.
\end{align}$$
This proves that $Z$ has the same distribution as $X$.

Thanks for the answer! Two questions:

So generally the proof is basically the same I would do in the case of a discrete distribution, but because I can't look at $\Pr[Z = x]$, I look at $\Pr[Z \leq x]$?
I can absolutely see intuitively that the two distributions must be equal. I guess this proof shows that for any interval, the probability mass is the same? Is that the best way to view it?


@Cryptonaut Two random variables are equivalent in distribution if they have the same cumulative distribution function--that is to say, the CDF uniquely determines a probability distribution.

ah yes. That all makes a lot of sense now. Thanks a lot!
